# Are all prime numbers Mersenne prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Sorry if this is a duplicate of a post, but I having trouble finding the answer anywhere. Are all prime numbers Mersenne prime? Or are there any numbers in between Mersenne primes?

Comment: $5$ isn't......

Comment: $2$ isn't........

Comment: I suppose lots of them aren't.  Did you do an internet search? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Comment: Of course not, but the largest known are Mersenne and the most other of the largest generalized Fermat primes since they are easiest to be proven prime and moreover give a better chance to find a prime than if one would take a random number.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed 2, 3, and 5 were prime and started calculating from these.

Comment: @Peter are there algorithms used to find large non-Mersenne primes?

Comment: @Matt  I'm confused.  2, 3, and 5 are prime.

Comment: @Matt $2,3,5$ are all prime. $3$ is Mersenne prime because it is $1$ less than a power of $2.$. But neither $2$ nor $5$ are one less than a power of $2$, so they are not Mersenne primes. $7$ is a Mersenne prime because $7 = 2^3-1.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson You can in principle search for all sorts of primes. First rule out small prime factors, then apply a miller rabin test (for example). If it is passed , chances are excellent that you found a prime. Proving the primality will only work if the number is special enough or not too large.

Comment: @Peter thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Mersenne primes are prime numbers, but the converse is not necessarily true. A Mersenne prime is $2^k - 1$, where $k$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to 2. Examples of Mersenne primes are $3$, $7$, and $31$. These are all also regular primes. However, counterexamples of primes that are NOT Mersenne primes are (as shown in the comments), $2$, $5$, or $11.$